# How to divide screen into three parts and add a screen after clicking button to existing screen in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

If the question is unclear , I want to make an email app just like windows 10 mail, which is divided into three sections first with buttons then next is for inbox and next is blank. On clicking the "New mail "button , a screen slides to write email and things. I am new to kivy please explain how to do this.

[image]

[image]

Main code :

```
import  kivy
from kivy.app import  App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class PyzzaDB(GridLayout):
    def send_email(self):
        pass


    def read_email(self):
        pass

class PyzzaDBApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

Pyzza = PyzzaDBApp()
Pyzza.run()
```

Kivy file :

```
#: import main pyzzadb
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton

<GridLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 2
    spacing: 2

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            source:"abc.jpg"
            size:self.size
            pos: self.pos


    Button:
        text:"Compose Email"
        size : 100, 30
        pos: 10,500
        on_press: root.send_email()
        background_normal : ''
        background_color: 1, .2, .5, .78
        on_press: root.send_email()

    Button:
        text:"Inbox"
        size : 100, 30
        pos: 10 , 470
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, .2, .6, .45
        on_press: root.read_email()
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: when you say *screen slides* do you mean a TextInput? 
I apologize but I do not use Windows; ;-)

Comment: I am not a regular windows user too, and I really appreciate the effort. I have added pics now. If the question is still unclear I can explain further.

Comment: In your code I do not see the second section.

Comment: I will do that later , for now I am concerned with "Newmail" button